# Finite-dimensional Lie algebra as a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras

Kindly asking for any hints about the following questions:

Suppose $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and $g$ is a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over $k$. Then $g$ is naturally equipped with the structure of an affine algebraic scheme. How?

Thanks for your help!